# React native hook state doesn't update inside a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-ios, use-effect

My mission is navigate to another screen if my **list.lenght is > 10.**
My **list** is updated correctly with hooks e redux.

I have ActionSheetIOS.showActionSheetWithOptions, and when i press "go", I'd like to check a list.lenght and check if it is > 10.

The state (list.lenght) updates correctly, but not in my function. In my function the state is the first state.

I have tried to put my function in the useEffect, I thought the value would update when updating the list, but it doesn't.

Here is my code

```
export default function CustomersList(props) {

    const userId = useSelector(state => state.loggedReducer.userId);
    const customers = useSelector(state => state.customers.customers);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = React.useState(false);
    const onRefresh = React.useCallback(() => {
        dispatch(fetchCustomers(userId));
    }, []);

    /**
     * Add Right icon on header
     * */
    React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
        props.navigation.setOptions({
            headerRight: () => (<Ionicons name="ios-more" size={24} color="white" onPress={() => {onPress()}} style={{marginRight: 20}}/>),
        });
    }, [props.navigation]);

    let clickGo;

    const onPress = () => {
        console.log("rendered");
        ActionSheetIOS.showActionSheetWithOptions(
            {
                options: ["Cancel", "go"],
                cancelButtonIndex: 0,
            },
            buttonIndex => {
                switch (buttonIndex) {
                    case 0: // cancel Action
                        break;
                    case 1: // Go
                        clickGo();
                        break;
                }
            }
        );
    }

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        console.log(customers.length); // updated state

        clickGo = () => {
            console.log("state", customers.length); // old state :(
            if(customers.length < 10){
                props.navigation.navigate("NewCustomer");
            }else{
                alert("upgrade to premium")
            }
        }
    }, [customers])

}
```

Comment: Why are you using `useLayoutEffect`?

Comment: it was my last try, before i used useeffect. but the result is the same. my state is not updating

Answer (score 0):

The logic for setting up `clickGo` is a bit off - the easiest fix is to just remove this logic and put it all in `onPress`

```
const onPress = () => {
    console.log("rendered");
    ActionSheetIOS.showActionSheetWithOptions(
        {
            options: ["Cancel", "go"],
            cancelButtonIndex: 0,
        },
        buttonIndex => {
            switch (buttonIndex) {
                case 0: // cancel Action
                    break;
                case 1: // Go
                    if (customers.length < 10) {
                        props.navigation.navigate("NewCustomer");
                    } else {
                        alert("upgrade to premium")
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Also - make sure you add your dependencies to the array in `onRefresh`!

Comment: I tried this first, but unfortunately putting a console.log, I realize that the value inside this function (customers.lenght) is the initial value of when the page is loaded for the first time. And it doesn't update with the list, but it always stays the same :(

Answer (score 0):

I have find the solution, I have put all script inside a useEffect like this.

```
useEffect(() => {

    console.log(customers.length);

    props.navigation.setOptions({
        headerRight: () => (<Ionicons name="ios-more" size={24} color="white" onPress={() => {onPress()}} style={{marginRight: 20}}/>),
    });

    const onPress = () => {
        ActionSheetIOS.showActionSheetWithOptions(
            {
                options: ["Cancel", strings.createNewCustomer, strings.connectWithCustomer],
                cancelButtonIndex: 0,
            },
            buttonIndex => {
                switch (buttonIndex) {
                    case 0: // cancel Action
                        break;
                    case 1: // Create new Client Action
                        if(!premium){
                            if(customers.length < 10){
                                props.navigation.navigate("NewCustomer");
                            }else {
                                Alert.alert(strings.upgradeToPremium)
                            }
                        }else {
                            props.navigation.navigate("NewCustomer");
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2: // Connect
                        if(!premium){
                            if(customers.length < 10){
                                openConnectModal();
                            }else {
                                Alert.alert(strings.upgradeToPremium)
                            }
                        }else {
                            openConnectModal();
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        );
    }


}, [customers])
```